# regExp code to compare a date format like this: DD-MM-YYYY HH-MM-SS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following piece of javascript to compare a DD-MM-YYYY HH-MM-SS date format, but for some reason it doesn't work. Can anyone see what is wrong with it? (mind that there is a whitespace between the date & time.

```
new RegExp (/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](\d{4})\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/)
```

The actual data I'm matching to this regExp looks like any of the following:
    1-1-2013 0:00:00
    1/1/2013 0:00:00 
    01-01-2013 00:00:00
    01/01/2013 00:00:00 
    31-12-2013 23:59:59 
These are the max ranges. Note that from 0:00:00 till 9:59:59 the time is noted like that and for 10:00:00 it's 6 digits, preferably it would handle leap years too.

Comment: You can just use the literal form for starters - `var regex = /your_regex/;`

Comment: In what way does it not work? It seems to work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by compare date format?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://regexpal.com/?flags=gims&regex=%5E(0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B12%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C3%5B01%5D)%5B%5C%2F%5C-%5C.%5D(0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D)%5B%5C%2F%5C-%5C.%5D(%5Cd%7B4%7D)%5Cs(%5B0-1%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B2%5D%5B0-3%5D)%3A(%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D)%3A(%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D)%24&input=11-08-1979%2012%3A34%3A59

Comment: Please provide an input for which it does not but should work.

Comment: How are you using it? What does the string look like that you're trying to match? Without telling us more about how it doesn't work and showing us the code you're using it in, we can't really help you. The regex looks fine.

Comment: Added extra details into the description to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the delimiter for the time is `:` and not `-`. Try:

```
new RegExp (/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](\d{4})\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])\-([0-5][0-9])\-([0-5][0-9])$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep things small and test little pieces of regex.

You want to allow one-digit for an hour, but you've forgotten to place it in your regex. It should look like that:

```
([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])
```

Now it works:

```
regex = new RegExp (/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](\d{4})\s([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/)
match = '1-1-2013 0:00:00'.match(regex)
console.log(match)
```